# MULTIPLE LEVELS AND MULTIPLE SOURCE INTEGRATION AT SAME TIME IN JW PLAYER?

Tags: video, jwplayer

I am trying to add multiple video levels (MP4 and WebM) at the same time along with multiple video Sources (HQ and SQ) but all the scripts that I have seen contains only one option. Can you please help me in this regards.

For example here is script of multiple sources:

```
<script>
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
playlist: [{
image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
sources: [{
file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4",
label: "360p SD"
},{
file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4",
label: "720p HD"
}]
}]
});
</script>
```

and here is script of multiple Levels:

```
enter code here<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
image:'http://d14nfturrc5hvw.cloudfront.net/70/192-webm-thumb-00001.png',
levels: [
{ file: "http://d1qr219t0s44x.cloudfront.net/70/192.webm", type:"video/webm" },
{ file: "http://d1qr219t0s44x.cloudfront.net/70/192.mp4", type:"video/mp4" }
],
width: '320',
height: '180'
});
</script>'
```

I need both levels and sources combined like wemb video in HQ and SQ as well as MP4 video with HQ and SQ.
Please help me how it is possible, I tried several methods but did not find correct solution. Thanks

Best Regards,
Ghazanfar Latif (Gabe)
www.prebinary.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levels is not a valid variable for JW6 - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6

I would think this should work as a set up:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      playlist: [{
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
        sources: [{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4"
        },{
          file: "/uploads/myVideo.webm"
        },{
          file: "/uploads/myVideoHQ.mp4"
        },{
          file: "/uploads/myVideoHQ.webm"
        }]
      }]
    });
</script>
```

However, you really only need webM now for Firefox for Mac and older Windows machines, as Firefox supports MP4 in  now in most cases. Pretty sure I would say that just using SD/HD MP4 files is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, that's right, i use this code and worked very well but the title of the video formats is shown as like " 1,2,3,4,...". I would like to change this title to custom text(e.g. 1080,720,...). I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Email JW Player support regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer of [@emaxsaun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645000/emaxsaun) and get true result, but i changed HD Quality Toggling labels by following code.

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key = "Your license Key";</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources: [{
                file: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4",
                image: "http://files.yyyy.com/users/201.jpg",
                label: "720p",
            }, {
                file: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/medium.mp4",
                image: "http://files.yyyy.com/users/201.jpg",
                label: "820p",
            }, {
                file: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/large.mp4",
                image: "http://files.yyyy.com/users/201.jpg",
                label: "920p",
            }]
        }],
        displaytitle: "true",
        stretching: "fill",
        preload: "auto",
        width: "100%",
        height: document.documentElement.clientHeight - 20,
    });
    jwplayer("myElement").onReady(function () {
        jwplayer("myElement").play();
    });
    jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function () { jwplayer().setFullscreen(true); });
</script>
```